# App not changing language if i provide it programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 2 strings.xml files in my app, 1 for "en" and other for "es".

I have added all necessary code, and it works fine.

If device language settings are "English", it launches the app with English strings.xml file, and if its Spanish, it loads Spanish strings.

But now i have provided a option to user to set language as well.

Now when i pass "en" or "es" to Locale helper class, it does not effect the app at all..Even restarting the app does not update the strings.

I execute following code when user updates the language.

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(getApplicationContext(), "es");
LanguagePreference.getInstance().setUserLanguage(getApplicationContext(), "es");
```

**This is my LocaleHelper class**
I think there is no issues here, otherwise default device language will also be not working.

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, LanguagePreference.getInstance().getUserLanguage(GlobalApplication.getAppContext()));
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, LanguagePreference.getInstance().getUserLanguage(GlobalApplication.getAppContext()));
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);


        Log.d("LocaleSet", language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        //   configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String tag = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.toLanguageTag();

and after check the 'tag' 
if(tag.contains("en"))
//your code
else if(tag.contains("es"))
//your code
```

OBS.: use try/catch